# Laravel 8 store files via SFTP

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, laravel-8

I am developing a Laravel 8 application, and I need to perform some operations to generate files.

In practice, I take the data from the DB, insert the data into an .xml file and finally insert the .xml file into a .zip file and download it.

I have implemented these operations and they work correctly, now I need to add a step, and this is to send the .zip file via SFTP.

Reading online and here on stack I have installed `league/flysystem-sftp` and configured SFTP in `config>filesystems.php` as follows:

```
'sftp' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => 'myserver.it',
            'port' => 2222,
            'username' => 'myusername',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'privateKey' => 'myprivateRSAKey',
            'root' => '/',
            'timeout' => 10,
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'permPublic' => 0766,
        ],
```

My SFTP server has the following folders:

```
/ -> folder1
   -> folder2 -> subfolder1
```

From the Laravel documentation, as this is my first time using SFTP, I used this code to save via SFTP

```
                //salvo sull'sftp
                $disk = Storage::build([
                    'driver' => 'sftp',
                    'root' => '/',
                ]);

                $disk->put($filename, $zip);
```

Here the problem arises, that is, I have no save on the SFTP server and I am no longer downloading the zipped file.

- my code to explain better:

```
//funzione per creare la spedizione
    public function creaSpedizione(Request $request)
    {


        //recuperpo le raccomandate
        try {

            set_time_limit(-1);

            //devo recuperare le raccomandate dal DB con isGenerated = 0 e per data e lotto

            //prendo la data odierna, devo spedire quelle con data precedente.
            //$date = date('Y-m-d');
            if ($request->input('sap') != 'all') {
                // qui recupero le raccomandate dello specifico SAP selezionate in fase di prenotazione

                $today = date("Y-m-d"); //recupero la data odierna
                $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $today);
                $daysToAdd = 1; //setto quanti gg aggiungere
                $date = $date->addDays($daysToAdd); //aggiungo un giorno

                $sap = Sap::select('id', 'sap')->find($request->input('sap'));

                //recupero le raccomandate
                $racc = Raccomandata::select('*')
                    ->where([
                        ['isGenerated', '=', '0'],
                        ['idCliente', '=', $request->input('sap')]
                    ])
                    ->whereDate('daSpedire', '=', $date)
                    ->get();

                //raggruppiamo per idCommessa e lotto
                $racc = $racc->groupBy(['idCommessa', 'lotto'])->toArray();
                
                //generazione file zippato
                $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                $data = date("Ymd");
                $sapMercurio = 'char10';
                $filename = $sapMercurio . '_' . $sap->sap . '_' . $data . '_001.cpx';
                $xmlname = $sapMercurio . '_' . $sap->sap . '_' . $data . '_001_I.xml';

                $this->prenota($filename, $sap->id);

                if ($zip->open($filename, \ziparchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
                    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
                }

                //INIZIO CODICE COMPRESSIONE DEI FILE XML (Compressione in zip, rinominato .cpx)
                $zip->addFromString($xmlname, \App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML', ['racc' => $racc]));

                // close and save archive
                $zip->close();

                if (file_exists($filename)) {

                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
                    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

                    // download zip
                    readfile($filename);

                    // delete after download
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                //FINE CODICE COMPRESSIONE FILE XML

                //salvo sull'sftp
                $disk = Storage::build([
                    'driver' => 'sftp',
                    'root' => '/',
                ]);

                $disk->put($filename, $zip);

            } 
      
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('L\'utente ' . Auth::user() . ' non è riuscito a prenotare la spedizione COD:' . $request->input('codice_prenotazione') . ' ERRORE:' . $e);

            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Non è stato possibile prenotare la spedizione numero: ' . $request->input('codice_prenotazione'));
        }

    }
```

I appreciate any advice or suggestions :-)

[EDIT]

I edit the question with the solution I found to the problem, hoping it will help other people with my problem.

First I had to change the SFTP permissions I used in `config>filesystems.php` and set them as 775 in the following way `'permPublic' => 775`.
After that I modified the `creaSpedizione` function as follows, since SFTP save I have to do it before downloading the zipped file.

- creaSpedizione

```
public function creaSpedizione(Request $request)
    {
        //recuperpo le raccomandate
        try {

            set_time_limit(-1);

            //devo recuperare le raccomandate dal DB con isGenerated = 0 e per data e lotto

            //prendo la data odierna, devo spedire quelle con data precedente.
            //$date = date('Y-m-d');
            if ($request->input('sap') != 'all') {
                // qui recupero le raccomandate dello specifico SAP selezionate in fase di prenotazione

                $today = date("Y-m-d"); //recupero la data odierna
                $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $today);
                $daysToAdd = 1; //setto quanti gg aggiungere
                $date = $date->addDays($daysToAdd); //aggiungo un giorno

                $sap = Sap::select('id', 'sap')->find($request->input('sap'));

                //recupero le raccomandate
                $racc = Raccomandata::select('*')
                    ->where([
                        ['isGenerated', '=', '0'],
                        ['idCliente', '=', $request->input('sap')]
                    ])
                    ->whereDate('daSpedire', '=', $date)
                    ->get();

                //raggruppiamo per idCommessa e lotto
                $racc = $racc->groupBy(['idCommessa', 'lotto'])->toArray();

                //generazione file zippato
                $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                $data = date("Ymd");
                $sapMercurio = 'char10';
                $filename = $sapMercurio . '_' . $sap->sap . '_' . $data . '_001.cpx';
                $xmlname = $sapMercurio . '_' . $sap->sap . '_' . $data . '_001_I.xml';

                $this->prenota($filename, $sap->id);

                //creo l'archivio .zip con nome $filename
                if ($zip->open($filename, \ziparchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
                    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
                }

                //genero il file xml, e lo aggiungo all'archivio .zip
                $zip->addFromString($xmlname, \App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML', ['racc' => $racc]));

                // close and save archive
                $zip->close();

                Storage::disk('prenotazionifiles')->put($filename, $zip);

                if (file_exists($filename)) {

                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
                    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

                    // download zip
                    readfile($filename);

                    //salviamo sull'SFTP
                    $this->storeSFTP($filename, readfile($filename));

                    // delete after download
                    unlink($filename);
                }
            }
```

- storeSFTP code

```
private function storeSFTP($filename, $zip)
    {

        try {

            Storage::disk('sftp')->put('folder2/subfolder1/' . $filename, $zip);

            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('SFTP SUCCESS: L\'utente ' . Auth::user() . '  ha caricato con successo il file: ' . $filename . ' via SFTP!, errore:' . $e);

            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Errore di comunicazione SFTP, se il problema persiste contatta un amministratore');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('SFTP ERROR: L\'utente ' . Auth::user() . ' non è riuscito a caricare il file: ' . $filename . ' via SFTP!, errore:' . $e);

            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Errore di comunicazione SFTP, se il problema persiste contatta un amministratore');
        }
    }
```